# Is this Romex ruined? Cut a hole on in-wall romex

Tags: electrical, wiring

Long story short: I accidentally cut this Romex that is located in a wall and carries the load for two receptacles.

Is this Romex ruined? Is it now a fire hazard? Do I have to call an electrician in to rewire the entire line (nooooooo)?[image]

Thank you for any help you can give me!

IMAGE:[image]

Comment: Did the wire get cut clearly in two?

Comment: I see no problem with the cable.  Tape it up and move on.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will be fine as it does not look like you damaged the actual conductor inside. Yes, the sheath is damaged; yes, the insulation on that one conductor is nicked, but I don't see any conductor wire exposed.

Look closely to ensure that the conductor is not damaged, than wrap it with good quality electrical tape and stop worrying about it.

If the conductor *is* damaged, you could use one of these fancy newfangled "in-wall" romex splices, rather than rewiring:

[image]